# Page level decision models

Tags: cdp, sitecore-personalize, decisioning

I have created one `Decision model`(ie:`GenderWiseDisscount`) with Male and female offers,

If User registered as Male  should trigger 15% off web experiences and Female should trigger 20% off web experiences on Webpage but I am not getting.

But I have tested Decision model in `Test Canvas` by selecting Male and Female Guest its showing correct offers but how I can implement this to be `trigger` on page level?

Comment: You might want to enable the QA tool and troubleshoot why it's not displaying.  For any site that has the Javascript Library added to it, you can append ?bxQATool=true to the URL, and it should give you information about what experience/experiment flows are triggered and why they might not display, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To activate a Decision Model, you will need to add it to an Experience. If you would like this offer to appear on a Web Page, the best thing would be to add the Decision Model to a Web Experience and use Page Targeting to target that specific web page.

These 2 docs sections might be useful:
https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-personalize/use-a-decision-model-in-a-web-experiment.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-personalize/composing-the-api-response-for-a-web-experiment.html

Comment: Hi Conor, welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. Can you enrich your answer by adding in more detail around the process of setting this up, and maybe include some screenshots?  We strive for answers that are not just link-only, which is mostly what this answer is.  Adding additional steps and context helps improve the quality of this answer, but also provides the question asker with more context than is provided in this answer, or the associated doc pages.